# Json Writes in Play 2.1.1

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

I started using the Playframework recently and am implementing a site using Play 2.1.1 and Slick 1.0.0. I'm now trying to wrap my head around Json Writes as I want to return Json in one of my controllers.

I've been looking at several references on the subject (like  [this one](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704756/how-to-implement-implicit-json-writes-of-embedded-object-in-play-framework-2-x)  but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I have a model looking like this:

```
case class AreaZipcode(  id: Int,
                     zipcode: String,
                     area: String,
                     city: String
                    )

object AreaZipcodes extends Table[AreaZipcode]("wijk_postcode") {

    implicit val areaZipcodeFormat = Json.format[AreaZipcode]

    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def zipcode = column[String]("postcode", O.NotNull)
    def area = column[String]("wijk", O.NotNull)
    def city = column[String]("plaats", O.NotNull)

    def autoInc = * returning id

    def * = id ~ zipcode ~ area ~ city <> (AreaZipcode.apply _, AreaZipcode.unapply _)
}
```

You can see the implicit val which I'm trying to use, but when I try to return the Json in my controller by doing this:

```
Ok(Json.toJson(areas.map(a => Json.toJson(a))))
```

I'm somehow still confronted with this errormessage:

```
No Json deserializer found for type models.AreaZipcode. Try to implement an implicit     Writes or Format for this type.
```

I've tried several other ways to implement the Writes. For instance, I've tried the following instead of the implicit val from above:

```
implicit object areaZipcodeFormat extends Format[AreaZipcode] {

    def writes(a: AreaZipcode): JsValue = {
      Json.obj(
        "id" -> JsObject(a.id),
        "zipcode" -> JsString(a.zipcode),
        "area" -> JsString(a.area),
        "city" -> JsString(a.city)
      )
    }
    def reads(json: JsValue): AreaZipcode = AreaZipcode(
      (json \ "id").as[Int],
      (json \ "zipcode").as[String],
      (json \ "area").as[String],
      (json \ "city").as[String]
    )
```

}

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[JSON Inception](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonInception) to the rescue! You only need to write

```
import play.api.libs.json._
implicit val areaZipcodeFormat = Json.format[AreaZipcode]
```

That's it. No need to write your own `Reads` and `Writes` anymore, thanks to the magic of Scala 2.10 macros. (I recommend that you read Play's documentation on [Working with JSON](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJson), it explains a lot.)

**Edit:**
I didn't notice you already had the `Json.format` inside the `AreaZipcodes` object. You either need to move that line out of `AreaZipcodes` or import it into your current context, i.e.

```
import AreaZipcodes.areaZipcodeFormat
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've been glaring at those docs for some time. And thanks for your proposed solution! However, if I replace my implicit val from the initial code block with your implicit object, Play starts to complain about the format method on the Json object. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a detail, a much concise syntax: implicit val areaZipCodeFormat = Json.format[AreaZipcode]

Comment: Oups, sorry about that, mistake while copying&pasting. @JulienLafont thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Carsten With that correction that's the exact same line of code which I supplied in my initial question. Somehow that still gives me the errormessage described :-(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't even see that line. Edited my answer, hope this will work.

Comment: Yes! Moved the implicit val to the controller and that did the trick. Thanks a million! Couldn't find the flaw :-).

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work for me. Why?

`type WeightedTerm = (String,TermWeight)`
`implicit val WeightedTermFormat = Json.format[WeightedTerm]`
gives compile error

No apply function found matching unapply parameters