# slick2 + play2 returns a collection of objects json format error

Tags: json, playframework-2.0, slick-2.0

**slick code:**

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], name: Option[String])

class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag, "app_user") {
    def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def name = column[String]("name", O.Nullable, O.DBType("VARCHAR(8)"))
    override def * = (id.?, name.?) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply _)
}

object UserHelper {
    val qUser = TableQuery[UserTable]
    def all: List[User] = db withSession { implicit session =>
        qUser.list.map(u => User.tupled(u.id, u.name))
    }
}
```

**play code:**

```
object UserController extends Controller {
    def index = Action {
        Ok(Json.toJson(UserHelper.all))
    }
}
```

**Compilation error:**

> No Json deserializer found for type List[User]. Try to implement an
>   implicit Writes or Format for this type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to implement implicit Json Writes of embedded object in Play Framework 2.x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704756/how-to-implement-implicit-json-writes-of-embedded-object-in-play-framework-2-x)

Comment: oh, I did not pay attention to the following method ~ Thank you @Peter