# How to implement implicit Json Writes of Future object in Play Framework 2.x

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I am new with play framework and i want to ask periodically to amazon about some products in order to insert them into a kafka topic, an error happens when i try to compile the code.

This is the code of the KafkaProducer:

file example.model.AmazonProducerExample

//UPDATED method with the suggestions from the users, thank you guys!

```
package example.utils

import jodd.lagarto.dom.{NodeSelector, LagartoDOMBuilder}
import example.model.AmazonProduct
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api.libs.json._
import example.utils._
import example.producer._

object AmazonPageParser {

private val topicName = "amazonRatingsTopic"

private val producer = Producer[String](topicName)


def parse(productId: String): Future[AmazonProduct] = {

val url = s"http://www.amazon.com/dp/$productId"
HttpClient.fetchUrl(url) map {
  httpResponse =>
    if (httpResponse.getStatusCode == 200) {
      val body = httpResponse.getResponseBody
      val domBuilder = new LagartoDOMBuilder()
      val doc = domBuilder.parse(body)

      val responseUrl = httpResponse.getUri.toString
      val nodeSelector = new NodeSelector(doc)
      val title = nodeSelector.select("span#productTitle").head.getTextContent
      val img = nodeSelector.select("div#main-image-container img").head.getAttribute("src")
      val description = nodeSelector.select("div#feature-bullets").headOption.map(_.getHtml).mkString

      val amazonProduct = AmazonProduct(productId, title, responseUrl, img, description)

      println("amazonProduct is " + amazonProduct.toString)
      amazonProduct
    } else {
      println("An error happened!")
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Invalid url $url")
    }
}//map
}//parse method

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

//Scala Puzzlers...
AmazonPageParser.parse("0981531679").onSuccess { case amazonProduct =>

  implicit val amazonFormat = Json.format[AmazonProduct]
  producer.send(Json.toJson(amazonProduct).toString)
  println("amazon product sent to kafka cluster..." + amazonProduct.toString)
}
}
}
```

file example.model.Models

```
package example.model

import play.api.libs.json.Json
import reactivemongo.bson.Macros

case class AmazonProduct(itemId: String, title: String, url: String, img: String, description: String)
case class AmazonRating(userId: String, productId: String, rating: Double)

case class AmazonProductAndRating(product: AmazonProduct, rating: AmazonRating)

// For MongoDB
object AmazonRating {
implicit val amazonRatingHandler = Macros.handler[AmazonRating]
implicit val amazonRatingFormat = Json.format[AmazonRating]
}
```

file example.utils.AmazonPageParser

The compiler returns me this error:

```
[error] /Users/aironman/my-recommendation-spark-engine/src/main/scala/example/producer/AmazonProducerExample.scala:25: No Json serializer found for type scala.concurrent.Future[example.model.AmazonProduct]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
[error]     producer.send(Json.toJson(amazonProduct).toString)
[error]                              ^
```

I have readed this [post with most votes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704756/how-to-implement-implicit-json-writes-of-embedded-object-in-play-framework-2-x) but it does not work for me.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: For `Future[T]` you'd better have `Writes[T]`, and call the write ops "inside" the `Future`

Comment: Hi cchantep, thanks for the answer. As i understand, you are referring to have the write operation to kafka topic will be inside the AmazonPageParser.parse method, isn't? but i would like to have this functionality in a decoupled way...

Comment: You should do the write once the future is completed, so using `map`, `flatMap` or for-comprehension with the appropriate op on the value. More a generic question about understanding `Future` for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Writes[T]` produces Json. You can't produce it directly from `Future` without blocking.

However you can add "callback" to this future, like this:

```
amazonPageParser.parse(productId).onSuccess { case amazonProduct =>
   producer.send(Json.toJson(amazonProduct).toString)
}
```

Or with other Future methods, like `map` or `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you @Tyth and cchantep. I will update the thread with the solution